# event.target.x on <i /> element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have `<i name="documentId" onClick={this.openDocument}/>` element, and onClick method:

```
openDocument(event) {
  const { name } = event.target;
  console.log('name', name);
  console.log('target', event.target);
}
```

The output is:

> name undefined
>
> target `<i name="documentId" onClick={this.openDocument}/>`

Any idea why name attribute is undefined even though logging the target clearly shows that element has it? And what would be the workaround for it? We have multiple documents, with different id's, name, which can be opened onClick, and i need a way to pass that name to the endpoint so it can know which document to return.

**UPDATE**

Here's fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/uwb0L9ae/

**UPDATE**

I've been able to get attribute values from **input** element is it only possible on those? Should i just wrap my  with input, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` attribute is not a valid attribute for the `<i>` tag, and hence it is unavailable from `event.target` directly, you could  get it like `event.target.getAttribute('name')`

The name attribute is available on following

```
<button>, <form>, <fieldset>, <iframe>, <input>, <keygen>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>, <map>, <meta>, <param>
```

Check **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)** documentation for more details

**[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l47pw9n9jm)**

Comment: @Andy What I meant to say is that it is not available directly under event.target

Answer (score 0):

If you can you should separate your JS from your HTML. You can attach an event listener to `document` and then get the target from the event:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.target;
  console.log(x.getAttribute('name'));
}
```

```html
<i name="image">This is a button</i>
```

Comment: "When using React you should generally not need to call addEventListener to add listeners to a DOM element after it is created. Instead, just provide a listener when the element is initially rendered." from the ReactJS docs. That `<i>` is actually a javascript object

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, yeah I only just realised this was tagged with React.